# Integrate pattern matching examples in mutt's Help

Tags: mutt

How can I integrate the following (scrapped from [mutt's manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#ss4.2)) in mutt's *Help*? Or, if one thinks it's better to call it independently, how to make it callable via a shortcut? Via a macro?

> Many of Mutt's commands allow you to specify a pattern to match
>   (limit, tag-pattern, delete-pattern, etc.). There are several ways to
>   select messages:
>
> ```
> ~A              all messages
> ~b EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the message body
> ~B EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the whole message
> ~c USER         messages carbon-copied to USER
> ~C EXPR         message is either to: or cc: EXPR
> ~D              deleted messages
> ~d [MIN]-[MAX]  messages with date-sent'' in a Date range
> ~E              expired messages
> ~e EXPR         message which contains EXPR in the Sender'' field
> ~F              flagged messages
> ~f USER         messages originating from USER
> ~g              PGP signed messages
> ~G              PGP encrypted messages
> ~h EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the message header
> ~k              message contains PGP key material
> ~i ID           message which match ID in the Message-ID'' field
> ~L EXPR         message is either originated or received by EXPR
> ~l              message is addressed to a known mailing list
> ~m [MIN]-[MAX]  message in the range MIN to MAX *)
> ~n [MIN]-[MAX]  messages with a score in the range MIN to MAX *)
> ~N              new messages
> ~O              old messages
> ~p              message is addressed to you (consults $alternates)
> ~P              message is from you (consults $alternates)
> ~Q              messages which have been replied to
> ~R              read messages
> ~r [MIN]-[MAX]  messages with date-received'' in a Date range
> ~S              superseded messages
> ~s SUBJECT      messages having SUBJECT in the ``Subject'' field.
> ~T              tagged messages
> ~t USER         messages addressed to USER
> ~U              unread messages
> ~v              message is part of a collapsed thread.
> ~x EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the References' field
> ~y EXPR         messages which contain EXPR in the X-Label' field
> ~z [MIN]-[MAX]  messages with a size in the range MIN to MAX *)
> ~=              duplicated messages (see $duplicate_threads)
> ```

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? I really do not understand what you are asking for, or what you are trying to achieve. Please edit your question.

Comment: @Juancho "Integrate in mutt's Help": We do know what is mutt's Help, right? Usually pressing <F1> will lead to the Help. How can the above be integrated --as in added-- to mutt's Help? Or, else, how can this list of helpful commands be called within from mutt, much like calling the Help? Of course I will edit the question if you still think it's unclear. Thanks.

Comment: The above table is already in mutt's help. In my version it is _Table 4.4 Pattern Modifiers_, starting at line 3670. I normally call help and then search for something like ~A (that is, press F1 for help, then /~A<enter> to search for the table.

Comment: Hmm? I don't see it! I press '?' (<F1> is actually unbound for me), then a long list with various commands appears, though the above are not there. I guess I explained it wrong after all and don't understand how to call the complete Help. I certainly can't see more than a few dozens of lines with '?'. Will investigate further.

Comment: Maybe I need to install the docs first, then add something like this `macro generic <f1> "!lynx /usr/share/doc/mutt/html/manual.html\n" "Show Mutt documentation"` in `muttrc` (scrapped from http://www.vinuxproject.org/wiki/muttrc).

Comment: My F1 key is bound to the macro `<shell-escape> zcat /usr/share/doc/mutt/manual.txt.gz | less`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22910/discussion-between-nikos-alexandris-and-juancho).

Answer (score 0):

First, the documentation files were missing (mutt was compiled without the `doc` USE flag, using Funtoo/Linux here).  Second, there was macro to call for the manuals in some way.

After compiling mutt with support for "doc", I added the following macros to be sourced from within muttrc:

```
macro generic <f1> "!w3m /usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.23-r6/manual.html\n" "Show Mutt documentation"
macro index <f1> "!w3m /usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.23-r6/manual.html\n" "Show Mutt documentation"
macro pager <f1> "!w3m /usr/share/doc/mutt-1.5.23-r6/manual.html\n" "Show Mutt documentation"
```

This is a working solution.  However, given that the docs are version specific, this means that the macros will need to be updated accorddingly for any new mutt version.